# Regex Not working

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I got this regex expression from REGEXlib and basically it checks to see if it is a valid UK DVLA Number Plate however i cannot get it to work within JavaScript could some one please help as im not the best with regex as it is.

```
//On change event for the textbox plate text
function setValue(target){
        var platetext = target.value;
        $('#numberplateyellow').empty();
        $('#numberplatewhite').empty();


        var plateregex = /([A-HJ-PR-Y]{2}([0][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[A-HJ-PR-Y]{1}([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30|31|33|40|44|55|50|60|66|70|77|80|88|90|99|111|121|123|222|321|333|444|555|666|777|888|999|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900))[ ][A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$/;

        if (document.platebuilder.target.value.search(plateregex)==-1){

        var answer = window.confirm ("Non LEGAL Plate Detected (YES WE WILL SHOW THE AGREE BOX ONCE I HAVE IT FROM TOM) \n\n Do you understand that this is now classed as a show plate ?");

        if (answer) {
        $('#numberplateyellow').append(platetext);
        $('#numberplatewhite').append(platetext);
        }

      }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Need more info. Can you give some example inputs? How is it going wrong? Why are you comparing document.platebuilder.target.value, looks like it is platetext that needs comparing?

Comment: Are you sure `document.platebuilder.target` is the same as the function argument `target`?

Comment: There are more: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=dvla&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20

Comment: well i need to check target.value thats the number plate being entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery and standard script.

Change `var platetext = target.value;`

to

`var platetext = target.val();`

and

`if (document.platebuilder.target.value.search(plateregex)==-1){`

to

`if (!platetext.match(plateregex)) {`