# Regex to match LEGAL UK Number Plate

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xhtml

i have been working on matching a legal uk number plate with the following regex expression , however this only matches new number plates like JS07 ZAS not the old J62 LNX format, i need a expression to match both and i cant work out how to match both type of plates.

```javascript
var plateregex = "([A-HJ-PR-Y]{2}([0][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[A-HJ-PR-Y]{1}([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30|31|33|40|44|55|50|60|66|70|77|80|88|90|99|111|121|123|222|321|333|444|555|666|777|888|999|100|200|300|400|500|600|700|800|900))[ ][A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}$";

if (!platetext.match(plateregex)) {
    var answer = window.confirm ("Non LEGAL Plate Detected ...");
}
```

well here is the regex expression i made to match both type of plates `^([A-HJ-PR-Y]{2,2}[056][0-9]\s?[A-HJ-PR-Y]{3,3})$|^([A-HJ-NP-Y]{1,3}[0-9]{2,3}?\s[A-Z]{3,3})$|^([A-Z]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4}([A-Z]{1,1})?)$|^([0-9]{4,4}[A-Z]{1,3})$|^([A-Z]{1,2}\s?[0-9]{1,4})$|^([A-Z]{2,3}\s?[0-9]{1,4})$|^([0-9]{1,4}\s?[A-Z]{2,3})$` however this dosent match anything ? when it should do can you see any problems here for using with javascript regex ?

(Editing on behalf of OP)  Here are some examples of UK registration plates that meet the OP's requirements.  The pattern is double letter followed by double numeric followed by triple letter.

```
ML09WKY
BF59DZR
GF54LFK
GL59FVM
LA55JVL
LB59AHD
GF59WUC
```

Comment: What _precisely_ are you having problems with? "I can't get my head around it" isn't a precise issue. :)

Comment: @user393273: I said _precisely_. We got that you're having problems or you wouldn't have posted the question. What approaches have you tried, and which inputs did those approaches fail to match?

Comment: @user393273: Perhaps I'm not making myself clear. I'm asking for _specific_, _actual_ examples of **individual inputs** to your code that are causing you problems. You need to narrow down the problem for us, because at the moment this question amounts to "do it all for me" (even though I know that's not your intention).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230433/regex-not-working)

Comment: Given that your "old" format is simply the previous format. Before that it was AAA 009 A (could be one, two or three digits). And before that there were other formats. And these are all still legal if an appropriate registration has been maintained (registrations can, for a fee, be transferred to a new car and thus preserved). Summary: to match all legal registrations just check it is an alphanumeric character sequence of length no more than seven(IIRC).

Comment: BTW "regex expression" has a redundancy. The "ex" part already stands for "expression". The term as a whole is a shortened form of "regular expression".

Comment: If you're asking for help on a regex, you should either give specific examples or a definition of what a legal plate is or both.  This is an international forum, and lots of us aren't familiar with UK-specific details.  Instead, you throw out a regex you think is wrong and ask us how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google gave me these

```
/\b[a-z]{2}([1-9]|0[2-9]|6[0-9]|1[0-9])[a-z]{3}\b/i      # current series
/\b[A-HJ-NP-Y]\d{1,3}[A-Z]{3}\b/        # previous series
/\b[A-Z]{3}\d{1,3}[A-HJ-NP-Y]\b/        # previous series
/\b(?:[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,4}|[A-Z]{3}\d{1,3})\b/     # old series - letters first
/\b(?:\d{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}|\d{1,3}[A-Z]{3})\b/     # old series - digits first
```

Looks like you'll have to test them individually.

Comment: @user393273: There is if you stick `|` between them, but why would you want to? Ew.

Comment: Not really since if you look at `current series` and `previous series` you'll notice the limit on characters `A-Z` and `A-HJ-NP-Y` which means if you left it with `A-Z` you'll get ones which are in the old series which contain a "Z" for example.

Comment: @James: It needs updating. In the "current series" that only supports the three blocks between Aug 2001 - Aug 2002. `51|02|52` might be better as `5[1-9]|0[2-9]|6[0-9]|1[0-9]`, off the top of my head.

Comment: @James: Well copying from Google is very clever of you, but the expression is still wrong.

Comment: i have just tried them individually and they are not working in javascript

Comment: @user393273: What the hell does "not working" mean? What inputs did you try? Do you practice being vague?

Comment: Sorry i tested the plate JS07 ZAS in javascript with /\b[A-Z]{2}(?:51|02|52)[A-Z]{3}\b/   as the expression and it didnt match it

Comment: @user393273 because Tomalak has already explained that the years provided in the regex are not right, they're outdated.

Comment: Because this part `(?:51|02|52)` should be (5[1-9]|0[2-9]|6[0-9]|1[0-9]), as Tomalak pointed out.

Comment: @user393273: Please take a careful read through [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Trying to employ this feature on your website without any fundamental understanding of Regular Expressions is dangerous.

Comment: Try this `/\b[a-z]{2}([1-9]|0[2-9]|6[0-9]|1[0-9])[a-z]{3}\b/i` you can't have spaces though... Draco beat me!

Comment: I'd be *very* tempted to write that as multiple regular expressions, not because they can't be combined, but because it makes it much clearer what is going on, which is going to help the next guy to reach that code ever so much.

Answer (score 2):

Angular ng-pattern:

```
ng-pattern="/\b[a-z]{2}([1-9]|0[2-9]|6[0-9]|1[0-9])[a-z]{3}|[A-HJ-NP-Y]\d{1,3}[A-Z]{3}|[A-Z]{3}\d{1,3}[A-HJ-NP-Y]|(?:[A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,4}|[A-Z]{3}\d{1,3})|(?:\d{1,4}[A-Z]{1,2}|\d{1,3}[A-Z]{3})\b/i"
```